# Jetpack Compose first argument modifier doesn't work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm learning Compose and I just wanted to style my item for my LazyColumn. However when I'm adding the first argument it seems to always reject it. Even when I delete the padding, the next argument will be in err.

Can anyone see something I'm missing because I've been looking at this for an hour.

```
@Composable
fun NewsArticleItem(news: News) {
    Row {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
        ) {
            Text(text = news.title, style = typography.h5)
            Text(text = news.body, style = typography.caption)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: The cose seems ok. Are you using the newest version of Android Studio, gradle and compose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass `dp` into `.fillMaxWidth()` You can pass `0..1` `Float` there, which will make it take part of available width, default is `1`

You can specify `dp` into `.width(56.dp)` modifier

If this didn't help, please specify which modifier exactly doesn't work in your case? Width fixed `width` modifier in my case everything seems work as expected

Comment: Please excuse me. I’ve updated the code to better reflect what’s going on. I pasted the wrong code. It’s the padding attribute.

Comment: Let me be clear; it’s the padding that’s shown in red in Android studio and I can’t figure out why.

Comment: @Nefario buids fine in my case. sure you have correct import?
`import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding`

Comment: Yes but for some reason it's greyed out. I'm using artic fox, could that be problem?

Comment: @Nefario sure, this means it uses some other `padding` in your code. check out your imports to see if there's another one ending with `padding`, or try to navigate into your `padding` source code so see which one is it

Comment: You’re absolutely right. I accidentally imported the Java padding package/library instead of the compose one. Many thanks!